# How to implement this exercise (dynamic array)?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having like an assesment exercise.

So given a Number, for example 12345, I must find out the sum sequence of the digits of the given number (1 + 2 +3 + 4 +5) and then add to it the result (15), and repeat this till the sum sequence of the last number is a digit (in this case is 6).

**Example :**  12345 + 15 + 6 = 12366;

666 + 24 + 6 = 696;

I've been thinkig to store the digits in an array, but then I realized the array's size is static. Now I'm thinking to make a linked list, but I'm not really sure. Does it involve linked lists?

Just guide me to the right path. What should I use?

Comment: [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: How big can your numbers be?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Please show your code attempts, and ask what is wrong with it. Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you can extract the digits from your Number, you don't need an array at all.  If you can't extract the digits of your Number, you won't have anything to put in an array.

Comment: If you are worried about the array being too small, make it really large. An array of size `1000` will not kill your computer and it is way more than you would need for this problem.

Comment: You don't need an array at all. Two int variables would do.

Comment: 666 + 18 + 9 = 693 ?

Comment: Are you asking how to check if the last digit is 6? In that case you don't need to store the individual digits. Just use modulo 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic needed here. Just do the obvious computation on integers:

```
int reduce(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (n != 0) { result += n % 10; n /= 10; }
    return result;
}

int your_problem(int n)
{
    int result = n;
    while (n >= 10) { n = reduce(n); result += n; }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/lGc9E1), [alternative demo](https://ideone.com/yNg03h).

Comment: Reduce might need a better name, though. Digit sum, sum of the digits, cross total.

Comment: @DanielJour: Yeah, `digit_sum` would have been better.